# how to handle NSButtonCell in NSTableView Dynamically?

Tags: objective-c

I am using NSArrayController binding to fill my table.I added NSButtonCell in a column of NSTableView. All checkboxes are selected already.HOw to get unckecked all the check at the time og nib loading.I am unable to handle the checkbox in NSTableView.

Answer (score 0):

If the `NSTableView` column is bound to your `NSArrayController`, their state should automatically be set to match the represented objects. If the checkbox isn't a part of your model, you can have them start off in `NSOffState`:

1. Go to the NIB file that contains the tableview
2. click to select the tableview, then the column, and finally, the cell.
3. Click a few times (I've forgotten how many) to edit the cell's value and you'll be able to turn it to the off state. They should show up off when you build your app.